# Java sorting indices in a new array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

Suppose I have an array test-

```
int[] test={5,4,3,2,1};
```

Now when I sort this array in increasing order I want to store the indices of the elements in a new array. So sorting the above array in increasing order should create a new array with values {4,3,2,1,0}
In C++ this is the code--

```
vector<int> order(n);
iota(order.begin(),order.end(),0);
sort(order.begin(),order.end(),[&](int i,int j){
     return test[i]<=test[j];
});
```

I wanted to know how I can implement this in Java using the comparator class

Comment: You should use ArrayList instead Vector, which as I understand has been deprecated for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort all the index by that index's value using `Comparator.comparing` this way

```
int[] res = IntStream.range(0, test.length)
                     .boxed()
                     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> test[e]))
                     .mapToInt(e -> e)
                     .toArray();
```

Output: `[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`